# Shift numpy array data to make it only grow

Tags: python, numpy

I have numpy array named `data_saw` that contains thousands of float numbers.

When visualized, it looks like this

[image: like this]

My task is to shift down each element before gap by `180` (because each gap range here is around `180`), so I will get continuous growing only line without gaps

[image: continuous growing only line without gaps]

I've ended up with looping through array and checking for a gap at every index (the last element is for comparison only and is not needed in further calculations, so it is just deleted after alignment):

```
for i in range(1, len(data_saw)):
    if data_saw[i - 1] > data_saw[i]:
        data_saw[:i] -= 180
data_saw = np.delete(data_saw, -1)
```

Trying to find out if there are more correct ways to do this with numpy array. Are there any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`np.diff`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) will tell you when the gap is bigger than some threshold

```
mask = np.diff(data_saw) < -90
```

To make `mask` the same size as `data_saw`, prepend a zero, because the result of `diff` is always smaller than the input by one element. For what I have in mind, you'll also want to convert to an integer type:

```
offset = np.concatenate(([0], mask)).cumsum()
```

To normalize the data, just add `180 * offset` plus some arbitrary bias:

```
data_fixed = data_saw + 180 * offset
```

To keep the last segment at its original value:

```
data_fixed = data_saw + 180 * (offset - offset[1])
```

To keep the second segment as-is:

```
data_fixed = data_saw + 180 * (offset - offset[-1])
```

You can use a similar method to adjust data not only with arbitrary numbers of gaps, but even arbitrary gap sizes above some threshold.

First, compute the indices corresponding to the orignal `mask` using [`np.flatnonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.flatnonzero.html):

```
delta = np.diff(data_saw)
indices = np.flatnonzero(delta < -90)
```

Now you can simply fill in the bad elements of `delta`, for example with the average of the two surrounding elements:

```
delta[indices] = 0.5 * (delta[indices - 1] + delta[indices + 1])
```

The fixed data is the cumulative sum (with a zero prepended):

```
data_fixed = np.concatenate(([0], delta)).cumsum() + data_saw[0]
```

Comment: I like this one. Just made a quick benchmark and this method occurs to be around 5 times faster than looping through array. Thanks for detailed solution.

Comment: I fixed the threshold. It should be `np.diff(data_saw) < -90`

Comment: Sure, `np.diff` returns negative values on gaps in my case.

Comment: @MasterDevX. I've added a generalized method for fixing gaps

Comment: Cool, that's really helpful and informative, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is more correct, but uses `numpy`'s native methods.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

array = np.arange(90)
array = np.concatenate([array[:30], array[30:] + 180, array[60:] + 2 * 180 + 30])
plt.plot(array)
```

[image]

```py
adjusted = array - np.concatenate([[0], ((np.diff(array) >= 180).cumsum() * 180)])
plt.plot(adjusted)
```

[image]